# Redis Error: Call to a member function connect() on null

Tags: laravel, redis

I have a queue and inside it I want to save some data into Redis cache. But whenever the jobs dispatched, it always give error `Error: Call to a member function connect() on null in D:\Software\xampp\htdocs\work\xtendanceweb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Redis\RedisManager.php:110`.

I think this is happened because my configuration isn't correct, but I don't have any Idea what's wrong

My .env

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
```

database.php

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],
```

cache.php

```
'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'cache',
            'lock_connection' => 'default',
        ],
```

My job function is simply get all data and save it to redis cache

```
public function handle()
    {
        $attendance = Attendance::all();
        
        Redis::set('attendance', $attendance);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to install predis with composer. run below command:

```
composer require predis/predis
```

second database.php file that its correct

finally you should go to config/app.php and find bellow code and uncomment this.

```
'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you have installed redis

```
composer require predis/predis
```

In your .env file make sure you have these

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Also, you need to uncomment Redis in your config/app.php

```
'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
```